# Open mail on selection change

Tags: javascript, forms, selection, mailto

I want to generate a specific mailto by choosing one option of a select box. If the users chooses option1 as subject, his mail program should pop up and open a new mail with the specific email adress.

This is my **HTML**

```
<form name="contactUS">
  <select class="mail_box" name="whoExactly" onchange="sendmail()>
    <option value="">Betreff auswählen</option>
    <option value="email1">Bewerbungen</option>
    <option value="email2">Genereller Support / Feedback</option>
    <option value="email3">Anfragen</option>
    <option value="email4">Copyright / Markenrechtverletzungen</option>
    <option value="email5">Sonstiges</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

And this my not working **Javascript**

```
function sendmail(){
 var whoto=contactUs.whoExactly.value;
 location="mailto:" + whoto + "@adress.com";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://liveweave.com/NDVtYH)

Comment: you have left out a `"`... see `onchange="sendmail()>`

Comment: @andymccullough true, but it didn't change the problem. My email app still doesn't open when choosing one option…

Comment: your `contactUs` is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sendmail(){
 var whoto=contactUS.whoExactly.value;
 location="mailto:" + whoto + "@adress.com";
}
```

note the capital 'S' in `contactUS`

http://liveweave.com/U4Q6j2

Or change your HTML to be camelCase